# Sorting on multiple columns in Linux

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a text file of data containing two numerical columns that need to be sorted in a nested way. Basically, I want to sort the data such that sorting

```
1 1
2 2
1 2
1 3
2 1
```

would produce:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
```

I have tried using the arguments -k1n -k2n but this does not work, presumably because it is not sorting simultaneously.

Comment: "using the arguments" to what?  What does "sorting simultaneously" mean?

Comment: What output are you getting? What's your `locale` setting?

Comment: @ScottHunter Presumably the `sort` command.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: You can also use `sort -k1,2n`

Answer (score 0):

There is some differences between sort among Linux/UNIXes… On OSX I have the possibility of simultaneously and in a stable way to sort under 2 columns (max) at the same time:

```
 -k field1[,field2], --key=field1[,field2]
         Define a restricted sort key that has the starting position
         field1, and optional ending position field2 of a key field.  The
         -k option may be specified multiple times, in which case
         subsequent keys are compared when earlier keys compare equal.
         The -k option replaces the obsolete options +pos1 and -pos2, but
         the old notation is also supported.
```

but it seems in Ubuntu Linux (I need it there), it does not have these many variations, but the specification of one column for sort so is impossible a stable sorting under 2 columns criteria.